# How to register this inside a function of a method?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, this

How to add this inside this functions of a method. Here is the codes

```
class Students {
  constructor (name, roll) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
  }
  document () {
     console.log(' this in method ', this);
    //  this inside function 
    function something () {
      // how to bind this inside this something function 
      console.log('this inside a function', this);
    }

    something.bind(this);
    something();
  }
}



const rejoan = new Students('Mohd Rejoan', 963782);

rejoan.document()
```

I am trying to get this inside the something function. I am trying to bind this function but not working as expected. Well, arrow function works fine but I want to know what's going on. Here is the live version of this codes => https://playcode.io/1038919

I have tryed to get the this object inside a function of a object method in javascript. But it's not working as expected. So I am expecting someone to solve this and explain this to me, how to solve this problem.

Comment: `something.bind(this)` returns the bound function, which you ignore ...

Comment: To bind `this` to `something` method, try `something.call(this);` or `something.bind(this)();`

Answer (score 0):

bind returns a function, you need to invoke that function

```js
class Students {
  constructor (name, roll) {
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
  }
  document () {
     console.log(' this in method ', this);
    //  this inside function 
    function something () {
      // how to bind this inside this something function 
      console.log('this inside a function', this);
    }

    let bindedFunction = something.bind(this);
    bindedFunction();
  }
}



const rejoan = new Students('Mohd Rejoan', 963782);

rejoan.document()
```